# Random Variables vs Dummy Variables

Tags: statistics

[image]

In the last sentence, since we're talking about a specific permutation, shouldn't it be denoted with lower-case $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ where $x_i \in X_i$?

Comment: It looks like $X_i$ is a random variable and $(X_1,...,X_n)$ is a random permutation, not an actual _specific_ ordering of $1,...,n$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $X_i=x_i$ rather than $x_i \in X_i$

Comment: A common convention in many US textbooks is that $X$ is a random variable and $x$ is an observed value of $X.$ The distinction is not always clear, and can depend on point of view. So your goal should be to understand the meaning for the purpose at hand, not to worry about the technical distinction. // In the quoted passage  I think it could be written either way. If it were "a particular permutation," then maybe you could argue for $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}.$